# pthread: locking mutex with timeout

Tags: timeout, pthreads, mutex

I try to implement following logic (a kind of pseudo-code) using `pthread`:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

threadA()
{
    lock(mutex);
    // do work
    timed_lock(mutex, current_abs_time + 1 minute);
}

threadB()
{
    // do work in more than 1 minute
    unlock(mutex);
}
```

I do expect `threadA` to do the work and wait untill `threadB` signals but not longer than 1 minute. I have done similar a lot of time in Win32 but stuck with pthreads: a `timed_lock` part returns imediately (not in 1 minute) with code `ETIMEDOUT`.

Is there a simple way to implement the logic above?

even following code returns `ETIMEDOUT` immediately

```
pthread_mutex_t m;
// Thread A
pthread_mutex_init(&m, 0);
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
// Thread B
struct timespec now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
struct timespec time = {now.tv_sec + 5, now.tv_nsec};
pthread_mutex_timedlock(&m, &time); // immediately return ETIMEDOUT
```

Does anyone know why? I have also tried with `gettimeofday` function

Thanks

Comment: The logic here is strange, your threadA locks the mutex twice. However the biggest issue is your threadA locks the mutex, while threadB unlocks it. You can't do that with pthread_mutexes, you have to unlock a mutex in the same thread that locks it.

Comment: You probably want something more like `pthread_cond_timedwait` but it's not clear what you are really doing, as nos stated above.

Comment: I really wanted to implement something like Windows Event. Yes, Duck, I've done it with conditional variables. Everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented my logic with conditional variables with respect to other rules (using wrapping mutex, bool flag etc.)
Thank you all for comments.

Comment: Would be fine to display here your implementation code example or some more descriptive text

Answer (score 1):

For the second piece of code: AFAIK pthread_mutex_timedlock only works with CLOCK_REALTIME.

- CLOCK_REALTIME are seconds since 01/01/1970
- CLOCK_MONOTONIC typically since boot

Under these premises, the timeout set is few seconds into 1970 and therefore in the past.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
class CmyClass
{
   boost::mutex mtxEventWait;
   bool WaitForEvent(long milliseconds);
   boost::condition cndSignalEvent;
};

bool CmyClass::WaitForEvent(long milliseconds)
{
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock mtxWaitLock(mtxEventWait);
   boost::posix_time::time_duration wait_duration = boost::posix_time::milliseconds(milliseconds); 
   boost::system_time const timeout=boost::get_system_time()+wait_duration; 
   return cndSignalEvent.timed_wait(mtxEventWait,timeout); // wait until signal Event 
}
```

// so inorder to wait then call the WaitForEvent method

```
WaitForEvent(1000); // it will timeout after 1 second
```

// this is how an event could be signaled:

```
cndSignalEvent.notify_one();
```